# How to let the left border overlap the bottom border on the bottom-left pixel?

Tags: css, border

Suppose I have the following CSS snippet:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-left-color: blue;
}
```

The left border is blue-colored, the bottom border is red-colored. But the bottom left pixel, where the left and the bottom borders overlap, is red in my browser. Apparently the bottom border overlaps the left border on that pixel.

Can I either manually set the overlap order or accomplish in another way that the left-bottom pixel is blue-colored instead of red-colored?

Comment: You're asking on a site that has the exact same problem =) Check the tabs on your profile, e.g the "summary" tab.

Comment: Seems like this is browser dependent. Do you really want to put that much effort into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894642/how-to-fix-this-white-dot-border-issue-in-a-drop-down-menu

Comment: @Niklas: I'm such a perfectionist. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The color of the bottom-left pixel belongs to your browser, you cannot override it.

However, you can use nested divs for this advanced situation. Try this:

```
div.parent {
    width: 200px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-color: blue;
}

div.child {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

And your HTML is:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Your content will appear correctly.
    </div>
</div>
```